# Help identify these two components

Tags: components, surface-mount, identification

I am trying to identify these components, and I couldn't find anything with just the marking. Any help is appreciated.
The first picture I thought is Passive crystal/oscillator!!! 
[image]

This one is marked 2058
[image]

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie It doesn't matter if you don't like the question, these questions are acceptable to the community. So try and help people and be nice.  Quote:"Questions on the repair of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired. See also: Is asking on how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?" https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6155/question-about-ic-identification-put-on-hold-as-off-topic/6157#6157

Comment: *these questions are acceptable to the community* To some of the community: yes. But I think there a similar number of people who are with me on this. I fail to see the relevance of such questions as they add nothing useful to this site. Also, often the people that ask do **nothing** with the answer. Often there is no reason that the component in question needs to be replaced. If OP would have taken the trouble to trace out the schematic, publish that here and then ask what the component could be then that could be useful as it teaches how to reverse engineer.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I have already identified two components that I am not familiar with just by checking the Related questions on the right. This is a double tiny sided pcb. It will take a lots of pictures and puzzling them to figure out the traces. The answer at the bottom is more like another question. I mentioned on my question that the first pic could be an oscillator. I did look around. I even looked at the smd markings pages and found nothing.

Comment: Component identification questions may be limited in future usefulness, but they are, as @laptop2d said, acceptable and have always been allowed AFAIK. Voting to leave open.

Comment: Either way, this should have been 2 different questions since the parts are unrelated.

Comment: Also the soldering on the 2058 thing looks highly questionable, so in case you are looking to replace these because they aren't working, then that might be why.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie "...such questions as they add nothing useful to this site." True. However, the site is also here for users problems even if nobody else needs the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is a crystal oscillator (look at these http://www.txccrystal.com/crystal.html)

The second one seems something like a dc-dc converter, where is it placed? What kind of pcb are you analysing? Can you put a picture?

Comment: *The second one seems something like a dc-dc converter* Nah, looks like an opamp, LED controller, voltage regulator or a comparator. If it is a DCDC converter, where's the inductor? Anyway, **it can be anything**. "It looks like" means nothing as all kinds of chips are sold in these 5-pin housings.